# contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior seems not act right for child UIControllerView 's UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

i use [WMPageController](https://github.com/wangmchn/WMPageController) as my one of viewcontroller, as we know , on iphoneX, scrollview will by default has a safeArea which constrain your content view in center ,that is top with 44 status height and 44 normal navibar height and to the bottom with 49 normal tabbar height and 34 home indicator height. then your scrollview can automatically be changed it's contentInset when scroll to the bottom to guarantee bottom contents of the scrollview will not be covered by home indicator, but when i use wmpagecontroller, it needs some uiviewcontrollers to make is easy to change vc in a single viewcontroller, then every single viewcontroller i test the scrollview in it , it runs with no problem,but when set to the umpagecontroller, i mean those controllers i set to doesn't be recognized its scrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior properly, when i scroll to the bottom, the outside vc(wmpagecontroller)'s home indicator is on my table cell's contents.

it‘s not normal , when i release my finger, the scroll indicator just clipped by the right bottom round corner ☹️

[image: un-normal indicator when scroll to the bottom]

when it's normal it should look like this.....

[image: normal indicator when scroll to the bottom]]

who knows how to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description/screenshot if the content inset on your tableview is correct. If it is, you can adjust the scroll indicator insets in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableView.contentInset
}
```

Additionally, you adjust the `tableView.contentInset` before `tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets` as needed.